# Not able to add information to child row of DataTables when clicking expand all

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, expand

I am trying to add data based on the parent row to the child row. When I click on expand all, I want to be able to add data to the child based on the parent. When I click on the button all the rows open but the container is only added to the first row with the information of the last row on the current page of the datatable

Here is my example:

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/objects.json',
        'columns': [
            {
                'className':      'details-control',
                'orderable':      false,
                'data':           null,
                'defaultContent': ''
            },
            { 'data': 'name' },
            { 'data': 'position' },
            { 'data': 'office' },
            { 'data': 'salary' }
        ],
        'order': [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if(row.child.isShown()){
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

    // Handle click on "Expand All" button
    // Handle click on "Expand All" button
    $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function(){
        let containers, user_name;
        table.rows().every(function(){
            if(!this.child.isShown()){
              $('#example tbody>tr').each(function() {
                user_name = $(this).find('.sorting_1').text();
                containers = document.createElement('div');
                containers.setAttribute('id', `container_${user_name.replace(' ', '_')}`);
                $(`#container_${user_name.replace(' ', '_')}`).text(user_name);
              });
               this.child(containers).show();
                $(this.node()).addClass('shown');
            }
        });
    });

    // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
    $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function(){
        // Enumerate all rows
        table.rows().every(function(){
            // If row has details expanded
            if(this.child.isShown()){
                // Collapse row details
                this.child.hide();
                $(this.node()).removeClass('shown');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-show-all-children" type="button">Expand All</button>
<button id="btn-hide-all-children" type="button">Collapse All</button>
<hr>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                    <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
                    <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

As you can see, when you click on `expand all`. Each of the rows is supposed to have a container with the name in the parent. In the screenshot below you can see `Airi Satou`'s child div has the name `Cedric Kelly`. Why is that happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have use `.each` loop inside your `every(..` loop its iterating twices i.e :  if `every..` loop is getting first row then `.each` loop is iterating through whole table(every tr in row) that's why only last value is shown inside `div`.

But , here there is no need to use `each` loop because you can get that `name` value by using `this.data()` it will return you *JSON Object* with all data from your row .So, just use `.name` to get name value and then add that value to the generated div using `.innerHTML`.

***Demo code*** :

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Full name:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.name + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.extn + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
    '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/objects.json',
    'columns': [{
        'className': 'details-control',
        'orderable': false,
        'data': null,
        'defaultContent': ''
      },
      {
        'data': 'name'
      },
      {
        'data': 'position'
      },
      {
        'data': 'office'
      },
      {
        'data': 'salary'
      }
    ],
    'order': [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });

  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });

  // Handle click on "Expand All" button
  // Handle click on "Expand All" button
  $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function() {
    let containers, user_name;
    var count = 0;
    table.rows().every(function() {
    //get data from row this will return values in json object..
      var d = this.data();
      if (!this.child.isShown()) {
        containers = document.createElement('div');
        containers.setAttribute('id', `container_${d.name.replace(' ', '_')}`);
        containers.innerHTML = d.name;//add value in inside div crated
        this.child(containers).show();
        $(this.node()).addClass('shown'); 
      }
    });
  });

  // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
  $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function() {
    // Enumerate all rows
    table.rows().every(function() {
      // If row has details expanded
      if (this.child.isShown()) {
        // Collapse row details
        this.child.hide();
        $(this.node()).removeClass('shown');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td.details-control {
  background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
  background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-show-all-children" type="button">Expand All</button>
<button id="btn-hide-all-children" type="button">Collapse All</button>
<hr>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isChildRowOpen = false;

$("#example tbody").on("click", "td.details-control", function () {
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var row = table.row(tr);

  if (isChildRowOpen) {
    // Close the child row if it is already open
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass("shown");
    isChildRowOpen = false;
  } else {
    // Display the child row and set isChildRowOpen to true
    row.child(format(row.data())).show();
    tr.addClass("shown");
    isChildRowOpen = true;
  }
});

// Close the child row if the user clicks the close button within it
$("#example tbody").on("click", ".close-child-row", function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var parentTr = tr.prev(".parent-row");
  var parentRow = table.row(parentTr);
  
  parentRow.child.hide();
  parentTr.removeClass("shown");
  isChildRowOpen = false;
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).